# How to check list of database in postgres present on non default port?

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu, psql

I have two postgres versions on my system. I want to check the list of database that is available on older version of postgres (port: 3433). Is there any way to check this?

Note - On running ***psql*** command it is showing the latest version of postgres that I have installed in system and ***\l*** command shows databases present in that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest variant is

```sh
psql -p 3433 -l
```

This assumes that you are operating system user `postgres`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to check the list of database using the following command -

`psql -h localhost -p 3433 -d test -U user`

Here -h represents the host, -p represents the port, -d represents the database and -u represents the username.

After that you have to enter the password and run command \l to view the list of database.